# Google Script Works Manually But not withTrigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I’ve written a script that gets data from one sheet and compiles it into a master-data sheet. The script is working when I run it manually but it doesn’t work with the time trigger I set up. I get the error “    Error   Exception: The starting row of the range is too small.
    at MasterDataCompiling(Code:63:42)

This is the code:

````
function MasterDataCompiling(){

var reporting_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10WGs5y3MERYezxdaN3ERKz37LiuQ6uDU6LCjo05IKvo"); 
var sheet = reporting_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Google Analytics Data");

// set and store a date object for today
var date = new Date();
var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3;
var two_days_ago = new Date(date - one_day);

Logger.log(two_days_ago);

// Get the range of dates to test
var daterange = sheet.getRange("A16:A1000").getValues();
//Logger.log(daterange);

// iterate the values in the range object
for(var i=0; i<daterange.length; i++) {

// Compare only month/day/year in the date objects
if(new Date(daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == two_days_ago.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {

 // if there's a match, set the row
 // i is 0 indexed, so add 3 to get the correct row
 var today_row = (i);    

 // rest of your code
}
}
var row_values = sheet.getRange(16+today_row,1,1,7).getValues();

var one_day_active_users = row_values[0][1];
var pageviews = row_values[0][2];
var total_events = row_values[0][3];
var adsense_rev = row_values[0][4];
var adsense_units_viewed = row_values[0][5];
var org_searches = row_values[0][6];
Logger.log(one_day_active_users, pageviews, total_events, adsense_rev,adsense_units_viewed, org_searches);

//youtube metrics

var youtube_sheet = reporting_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Youtube");
var youtube_daterange = youtube_sheet.getRange("A2:A1000").getValues();

// Logger.log(youtube_daterange);

// iterate the values in the range object
for(var i=0; i<youtube_daterange.length; i++) {


// Compare only month/day/year in the date objects
if(new Date(youtube_daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == two_days_ago.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {

 // if there's a match, set the row
 // i is 0 indexed, so add 3 to get the correct row
 var youtube_today_row = (i);  
 Logger.log(youtube_today_row);

 // rest of your code
}
}

var youtube_row_values = youtube_sheet.getRange(2+youtube_today_row,1,1,8).getValues();

var est_views = youtube_row_values[0][1];
var est_min_watched = youtube_row_values[0][2];
var yt_likes = youtube_row_values[0][3];
var yt_dislikes = youtube_row_values[0][4];
var yt_comm = youtube_row_values[0][5];
var yt_subs_gain = youtube_row_values[0][6];
var yt_subs_lost = youtube_row_values[0][7];

Logger.log(est_views, est_min_watched, yt_likes, yt_dislikes, yt_comm, yt_subs_gain, yt_subs_lost);

//insta metrics

var insta_sheet = reporting_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Instagram");
var insta_daterange = insta_sheet.getRange("A2:A1000").getValues();

// iterate the values in the range object
for(var i=0; i<insta_daterange.length; i++) {
// Logger.log(insta_daterange[i], two_days_ago);


// Compare only month/day/year in the date objects
if(new Date(insta_daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == two_days_ago.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {

 // if there's a match, set the row
 // i is 0 indexed, so add 3 to get the correct row
 var insta_today_row = (i);  
 Logger.log(insta_today_row);

 // rest of your code
}
}

var insta_row_values = insta_sheet.getRange(2+insta_today_row,1,2,10).getValues();

var followers = insta_row_values[1][1];
var following = insta_row_values[1][2];
var posts = insta_row_values[1][3];
var daily_views = insta_row_values[0][4];
var engagements = insta_row_values[0][5];
var ig_video_views = insta_row_values[0][6];
var ig_comments = insta_row_values[0][7];
var ig_website_clicks = insta_row_values[0][8];

Logger.log(followers, following, posts, daily_views, engagements, ig_video_views, ig_comments, ig_website_clicks);

SpreadsheetApp.flush();

var blog_sheet = reporting_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Website");
var blog_cat_count = blog_sheet.getRange("I4:I15").getValues();

var fitness = blog_cat_count[0][0];
var gen_info = blog_cat_count[1][0];
var mental = blog_cat_count[2][0];
var news = blog_cat_count[3][0];
var nutrition = blog_cat_count[4][0];
var physio = blog_cat_count[5][0];
var gear = blog_cat_count[6][0];
var rules = blog_cat_count[7][0];
var tactics = blog_cat_count[8][0];
var techniq = blog_cat_count[9][0];
var uncat = blog_cat_count[10][0];
var workout = blog_cat_count[11][0];  
var total_posts_blog = blog_sheet.getRange("J4").getValue();

var pasting_array = [[two_days_ago,
                    one_day_active_users,
                    pageviews,
                    total_events,
                    adsense_rev,
                    adsense_units_viewed,
                    org_searches,
                    total_posts_blog,
                    fitness,
                    gen_info,
                    mental,
                    news,
                    nutrition,
                    physio,
                    gear,
                    rules,
                    tactics,
                    techniq,
                    uncat,
                    workout,
                    est_views,
                    est_min_watched,
                    yt_likes,  
                    yt_dislikes,
                    yt_comm,
                    yt_subs_gain,
                    yt_subs_lost,
                    followers,
                    following,
                    posts,
                    daily_views,
                    engagements,
                    ig_video_views,
                    ig_comments,
                    ig_website_clicks]]

Logger.log(pasting_array);

var copyToSheet = reporting_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master Data");

copyToSheet.getRange(copyToSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1,1,35).setValues(pasting_array);                     

}
 ```

Any idea why this would be happening?
````

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, of course free of sensitive information, so that this behaviour can be reproduced?

Comment: You just think that you code works but it really doesn't.  You have a lot of errors in there.  When you want to refer to a single cell in a column of cell obtained with getValues() you still two indices.  One for the row and one for the column.  So they tend to look like value[i][0]; Also when you want to compare dates you'll want to use either Date().getTime() or Date.valueOf().  I was going through your code but it's too big of a job to do especially without data to test it with.  Your going to have to do some debugging and testing and narrow your problem area down quite a bit.

Comment: @lamblichus yes, here’s a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-rpAtxQ59xusHUNSxjkQ7ZnDJtZ9igL2uFPGWjjH98

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the variables `today_row` and `youtube_today_row` inside an `if` statement, and using those variables outside the statement. This is really bad practice since, if the script never gets inside the `if` block, the script will try to use an undefined variable. To avoid this, you should define these variables outside the `if` statement, and provide an initial value for it (so that you can use it even if the script never goes inside the `if` statement).

That is to say, you should change this:

```js
for(var i=0; i<daterange.length; i++) {
  if(new Date(daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == two_days_ago.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    var today_row = (i);    
  }
}
```

To this:

```js
var today_row = 0;
for(var i=0; i<daterange.length; i++) {
  if(new Date(daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == two_days_ago.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    today_row = i;    
  }
}
```

And this:

```js
for(var i=0; i<youtube_daterange.length; i++) {
  if(new Date(youtube_daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == two_days_ago.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    var youtube_today_row = (i);
  }
}
```

To this:

```js
var youtube_today_row = 0;
for(var i=0; i<youtube_daterange.length; i++) {
  if(new Date(youtube_daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) == two_days_ago.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    youtube_today_row = i;
  }
}
```